# Port Forwarding (NAT UPNP) ERROR

Tags: c#, upnp, portforwarding

Im trying to set port forwarding using c#, but I keep getting this error in visual studio.

`Interop type 'NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.`

this is the code:

```
NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass upnpnat = new NATUPNPLib.UPnPNATClass();
NATUPNPLib.IStaticPortMappingCollection mappings = upnpnat.StaticPortMappingCollection;
mappings.Add(9099, "UDP", 9099, "192.168.1.101", true, "Local Web Server");
```

Any Ideas?

I found the code [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/02/05/NET-Framework-Communicate-through-NAT-Router-via-UPnP.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find the reference to NATUPNPLib in the solution explorer, select it and in the Properties tab change "Embed Interop Types" to FALSE and then rebuild.